# Hive: Fast concatenate two tables into one?

Tags: hadoop, hive, concatenation

I have two Hive tables of the same structure (schema). What would be an efficient SQL request to concatenate them into a single table with the same structure?

Update, this works quite fast in my case:

CREATE TABLE xy AS SELECT *
   FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM y
  ) tmp;

Comment: Did you try anything without success?

Comment: Please see my question update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to merge `table_A` and `table_b` into a single one, the easiest way is to use the `UNION ALL` operator. You can find the syntax and use cases here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union

Answer (score 1):

"union all" is a right solution but might be expensive, resource/time wise. I'd recommend creating a table with two partitions, one for table A and another for Table B. This way, no need to merge (or union all). The merged table is available as soon as both partitions get populated.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution to what I need, could you explain how you do this?